# Find savefile of ongoing private flash game

Tags: firefox, adobe-flash, private-browsing

I am trying to find the schedule location of a flash game that is currently being played in firefox's "private" browsing mode. The game only saves to local storage and since the browser is in "private" mode it is not in its normal spot at `%AppData\Macromedia\#SharedObjects`. This is on Windows 10 with the latest version of firefox. It is flash 23.XX if I remember correctly.

I have already tried seaching the open handles of `plugin-container` but to no avail. I have also tried searching `.sol` in any open handle with process explorer but it came up empty.